# Gibbons-Hawking-York (GHY) boundary term

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, lagrangian-formalism, action, boundary-terms

In the Hilbert action, apart from the bulk term, there is a boundary term called GHY $\int d^{3}x\sqrt{h}K$. Why do we choose to calculate this on the $r=$constant hypersurface instead of the $t=$const or $\theta, \phi=$ const?

Comment: Mathematically you could hold it fixed on any surface you want, but what is the physical interpretation? The reason we use constant r for large r is that we are considering spacetimes with certain fall offs for large radius. If you hold the metric fixed at a $\theta =$ const surface, aside from that being topologically ill defined, why would you expect the metric to be fixed on such a surface?

Comment: Yes that makes sense for the angular variables. By why not hold it fixed on the t=constant hypersurface?  Btw thank you for the response!

Comment: Well $t$ is the time variable so it's a bit different. The idea of Lagrangian mechanics is that if you specify the metric on a space slice at $t_1$ and $t_2$, then the "path" between the two configurations will extremize the action. So in that sense you are already holding those fixed as part of the minimization problem. The need for the GHY boundary term is different, it's needed to make the variation of the action itself well defined. This is shown for instance in Erik Poisson's book 'A Relativist's Toolkit.'

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thank you!